# How to do a parameterized remote trigger from a post build task?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins job with a post build task. The post build task is a regex expression. If the regex condition it met, I want to do a parameterized remote trigger to trigger another jenkins build. From [post build task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) I see that the regex condition can trigger a script. Is it possible to have it trigger a [parameterized remote trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin)?

Basically, I only want to do the second build if the regex condition is met from the first build. I don't want to have a script that executes a CURL to achieve it. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using the [Post-Build Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin). You select it under the Post-build Actions of your job configuration in Jenkins. My groovy script performs a regex on the build log of my original job. If the regex condition is met, it triggers a new build.

Below is the example from the Groovy Plugin:

```
def job = Hudson.instance.getJob('MyJobName')
def anotherBuild
try {
    def params = [
      new StringParameterValue('FOO', foo),
    ]
    def future = job.scheduleBuild2(0, new Cause.UpstreamCause(build), new ParametersAction(params))
    println "Waiting for the completion of " + HyperlinkNote.encodeTo('/' + job.url, job.fullDisplayName)
    anotherBuild = future.get()
} catch (CancellationException x) {
    throw new AbortException("${job.fullDisplayName} aborted.")
}
```